# How to resolve fractions and subtraction in a pandas string column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, numeric

I have a dataframe column that includes fractions and subtraction, like so:

```
60
12.5
6/12
2021-1988
NaN
8/12
3
NaN
2021-2004
5
```

It's in string format right now. I want it to be numeric. However, when I try to_numeric, it doesn't process the "math" in the column. I guess I could split the values on their operators and go from there. Any more elegant/streamlined ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.eval`:

```
df['YOUR COLUMN'] = pd.eval(df['YOUR COLUMN'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   YOUR COLUMN
0    60.000000
1    12.500000
2     0.500000
3    33.000000
4     0.666667
5     3.000000
6    17.000000
7     5.000000
```